Ejabberd Access to WebAdmin page vhosts/ for account
On my Ubuntu version 22 I have installed Ejabberd according to docs.ejabberd.im. Everything worked fine and made the minimum changes succesfull and registered a member and made the member admin in the conf ejabberd.yml file.
But when I login in to the admin panel: https://exdomain.com:5443 I get the login popup/dialog and can succesfully login as a admin. But when i visit the pages like vhosts, nodes, multichat etc.. the page gets loaded but now data is visible.
When I view my logs I see the following error:
@ejabberd_web_admin:process_admin/3:524 Access to WebAdmin page vhosts/ for account admin@exdomain.com was denied

I made the following changes:
/opt/ejabberd/conf/ejabberd.yml
hosts:
  - exdomain.com

...

acl:
  admin:
    user: admin@exdomain.com
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128

I have got the SSL fixed and put the ports open.
But somehow I can't get the problem fixed.
Am I missing something?

There are two possible reasons: there's a bug in ejabberd 24.06, or it could be a configuration problem.
Both problems and how to solve them are described in
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/4249
